# Angular Application is not working on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, angular-ui-router, production-environment

I am try publish my application on IIS,but when i try refresh i am getting

**Error**

```
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory..
```

**Application Path**

```
 E:\tutorial\Angular Login\front\clientapi
```

**Angular build**

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/eclipse/
```

After Application build i get following output in **dist** folder

[image]

I copy the **clientapi** folder and paste it to **C:\ecilpse** folder

[image]

Then Publish on **IIS**
[image]

After that i add web.config file on **eclipse** folder

```
<configuration>

<system.webServer>

  <rewrite>

    <rules>

      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">

        <match url=".*" />

        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />

          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

        </conditions>

        <action type="Rewrite" url="/eclipse/" />

        <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->

      </rule>

    </rules>

  </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the directory name (`ecilpse`)

Comment: @GabrielNegut,  i just change but i am still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by following steps.

1. Copy All files from `dist\clientapi`
2. Paste into `c:\eciplse`
3. Update Web.config file with `<action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />`